# How to convert 2 range(class) into 1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I got two different range as :
 `var range1 = sheet.getRange("A1");` and `var range2 = sheet.getRange("B4");`

How can I convert them to get one range as `var range = sheet.getRange("A1:B4")` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here - the pseudo code example you gave is exactly how you'd do that.

Comment: I need to do that with the 2 variables i got. I can't declare it directly in my code as i don't know yet what range1 and range2 will be.

Comment: You can use `getA1Notation()` to get the string

Answer (score 2):

You can use the variable names in the `.getRange();` method.

```
function getRange(){

 var range1 = "a1";
 var range2 = "c4";  

 var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range1 + ":" + range2);

}
```

Comment: In your exemple range1 and range2 are strings, but in my problem they are range class, can i still get a string from them ?

Comment: You're question doesn't convey the problem you have. You'll have to add more detail or provide a spreadsheet when we can try to understand your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thx to @TheMaster I can use `getA1Notation()` to do something like :

`var range = sheet.getRange(range1.getA1Notation() + ":" + range2.getA1Notation());`